# Error reading binary file

Tags: javascript, filereader, typed-arrays

I'm trying to read a binary file in JavaScript.

However, it is not returning anything. What's wrong with the command below?

```
function autenticarbiometria() { 
   var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
   var file = fileInput.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   var campo = "";
   var status = "f";

   filereader.onload = function(e) {
      var campo = reader.result;
      document.getElementById('template').value = campo;
      alert("CAMPO TAMANHO --> " + campo.length);
   }
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayBuffer` cannot be set as string. You need to convert the content to a string, or a Base-64 / hex representation if the binary data is not printable.

For text you can use the new [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) object (may need [polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) in some browsers).

**Example**

```
var td = new TextDecoder("utf-8");  // or use utf-16 etc. depending on what you expect
var txt = td.decode(campo);         // pass in the ArrayBuffer
```

Now `txt` can be set as string source for your element (if readable).

Also note that you have a local var of `campo` which overrides the parent var `campo`.

Answer (score 2):

Should it not be:

```
var fr = new FileReader;
var txt = fr.readAsText(document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]);
fr.onloadend = function(r){
  console.log(r);
}
```

Comment: This is actually a good point. I assumed he wanted to read binary due to the title, but this could be easier if text is the goal.